# Delphi Array of Pointers

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointers

I have problems when I try to write an array of pointers to a file:

```
type

  PInt = ^Int64;

  TArray = Array[ 0..5 ] of PInt;

procedure Save( AFileHandle: THandle; AArray: TArray );
begin
  FileWrite( AFileHandle, AArray[ 0 ]^, Length( AArray ) * SizeOf( PInt ) );
end;

procedure Load( AFileHandle: THandle; AArray: TArray );
var
  I: Int32;
begin
  for I := 0 to Length( AArray ) - 1 do
    AArray[ I ] := AllocMem( SizeOf( PInt ) );
  FileRead( AFileHandle, AArray[ 0 ]^, Length( AArray ) * SizeOf( PInt ) );
end;
```

Can avoid writing every single item by writing everything at once?

Thanks.

Comment: if you have only pointers to <anytype> in the array there is no other way i think.
Or copy it first to a Array of int64 and write that.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: **Why on earth are you writing pointers to a file?** They are very likely not valid anymore when you read them back. Write the Int64s instead.

Comment: I don't try write pointers! But value of pointers.
I have simplified, indeed I have an array of record pointers.
For performance issues I wanted to write all at once. Writing first in a stream or in a record array is lost a lot.

Comment: Thats like eggs, if you want to put them in a box you have to collect them first. There i no other way

Comment: If your source buffers were whole-page-sized, you could use [`WriteFileGather`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365749.aspx). If your destination were a socket instead of a file, you could use [`WSASend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742203.aspx). If you were using Linux, you could use [`writev`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/writev). Otherwise, you can only write one contiguous buffer at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is slightly confusing. I can't imagine that you are trying to actually write the **pointers** themselves (they would very likely be invalid when you read them back), just the `Int64`s they point to. If that is the case, you are not doing it right.

If the array really contains pointers, then you can't write the items in one go. **The pointers are in one contiguous block, but not necessarily the items they point to**. You will have to write them one by one:

```
procedure Save(AFileHandle: THandle; AArray: TArray);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(AArray) to High(AArray) do
    FileWrite(AFileHandle, AArray[I]^, SizeOf(Int64));
end;
```

or, alternatively:

```
procedure Save(AFileHandle: THandle; AArray: TArray);
var
  P: PInt;
begin
  for P in AAray do
    FileWrite(AFileHandle, P^, SizeOf(P^));
end;
```

And reading back:

```
procedure Load(AFileHandle: THandle; var AArray: TArray);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(AArray) to High(AArray) do
  begin
    New(AArray[I]);
    FileRead(AFileHandle, AArray[I]^, SizeOf(Int64));
  end;
end;
```

You read and write `SizeOf(PInt)`, but that would write the size of a pointer, not the size of an `Int64`.

---

As Sertac writes, you could write them in one go (and read them too), thus avoiding having to call `FileWrite` or `FileRead` repeatedly, if you copy the `Int64`s to a contiguous block first (assuming that each call to file I/O is much slower than copying the values to a single array):

```
type
  PSaveArray = ^TSaveArray;
  TSaveArray = array[0..5] of Int64;

procedure Save(AFileHandle: THandle; AArray: TArray);
var
  Save: TSaveArray;
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 5 do
    Save[I] := AArray[I]^;
  FileWrite(AFileHandle, Save, SizeOf(Save));
end;
```

Reading back would be similar:

```
procedure Load(AFileHandle: THandle; var AArray: TArray);
var
  Items: PSaveArray;
  I: Integer;
begin
  New(Items);
  FileRead(AFileHandle, Items^, Sizeof(Items^));
  for I := Low(Items) to High(Items) do
    AArray[I] := Addr(Items^[I]);
end;
```

Comment: If the question is as you've understood, you can populate an array first and then write it once. It will lift the burden from file I/O.

Comment: Yes, that would be a possibility. More work, but probably faster. I'll add that.

Comment: Ok, was enough "then you can't write the items in one go". Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the values are scattered over the heap, you can use Scatter-Gather IO to read/write them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/reading-from-or-writing-to-files-using-a-scatter-gather-scheme

However, it's probably easier to do "gather-before-write" yourself rather than deal with those functions. Consider also that these function are OS-specific, so this approach is not cross-platform.